Replica Not Starting
I’m trying to setup a primary-secondary replica. This is to do a downtime-free migration from first node to second node in the next few days.
The primary node has been setup, the config was updated, I added the keyfile. Did the same with secondary node.
I also initialized the replication, added the secondary node to the replication. I can see a ping and uptime, but the secondary node is stuck in “STARTUP”.
However, there’s no replica config on the secondary node. Furthermore, it’s vomiting this all over the error log again and again.
Secondary Node (Logs):
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-14T11:35:14.018+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONNPOOL", "id":22576,   "ctx":"ReplNetwork","msg":"Connecting","attr":{"hostAndPort":"Ubuntu-2204-jammy-amd64-base:27017"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-14T11:35:14.818+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":7012500, "ctx":"QueryAnalysisConfigurationsRefresher","msg":"Failed to refresh query analysis configurations, will try again at the next interval","attr":{"error":"PrimarySteppedDown: No primary exists currently"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-14T11:35:15.000+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"QUERY",    "id":23799,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Aggregate command executor error","attr":{"error":{"code":26,"codeName":"NamespaceNotFound","errmsg":"Unable to retrieve storageStats in $collStats stage :: caused by :: Collection [local.oplog.rs] not found."},"stats":{},"cmd":{"aggregate":"oplog.rs","cursor":{},"pipeline":[{"$collStats":{"storageStats":{"waitForLock":false,"numericOnly":true}}}],"$db":"local"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-14T11:35:15.000+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"QUERY",    "id":23799,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Aggregate command executor error","attr":{"error":{"code":26,"codeName":"NamespaceNotFound","errmsg":"Unable to retrieve storageStats in $collStats stage :: caused by :: Collection [config.transactions] not found."},"stats":{},"cmd":{"aggregate":"transactions","cursor":{},"pipeline":[{"$collStats":{"storageStats":{"waitForLock":false,"numericOnly":true}}}],"$db":"config"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-14T11:35:15.001+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"QUERY",    "id":23799,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Aggregate command executor error","attr":{"error":{"code":26,"codeName":"NamespaceNotFound","errmsg":"Unable to retrieve storageStats in $collStats stage :: caused by :: Collection [config.image_collection] not found."},"stats":{},"cmd":{"aggregate":"image_collection","cursor":{},"pipeline":[{"$collStats":{"storageStats":{"waitForLock":false,"numericOnly":true}}}],"$db":"config"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-14T11:35:15.018+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONNPOOL", "id":22576,   "ctx":"ReplNetwork","msg":"Connecting","attr":{"hostAndPort":"Ubuntu-2204-jammy-amd64-base:27017"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-14T11:35:16.000+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"QUERY",    "id":23799,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Aggregate command executor error","attr":{"error":{"code":26,"codeName":"NamespaceNotFound","errmsg":"Unable to retrieve storageStats in $collStats stage :: caused by :: Collection [local.oplog.rs] not found."},"stats":{},"cmd":{"aggregate":"oplog.rs","cursor":{},"pipeline":[{"$collStats":{"storageStats":{"waitForLock":false,"numericOnly":true}}}],"$db":"local"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-14T11:35:16.000+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"QUERY",    "id":23799,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Aggregate command executor error","attr":{"error":{"code":26,"codeName":"NamespaceNotFound","errmsg":"Unable to retrieve storageStats in $collStats stage :: caused by :: Collection [config.transactions] not found."},"stats":{},"cmd":{"aggregate":"transactions","cursor":{},"pipeline":[{"$collStats":{"storageStats":{"waitForLock":false,"numericOnly":true}}}],"$db":"config"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-14T11:35:16.001+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"QUERY",    "id":23799,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Aggregate command executor error","attr":{"error":{"code":26,"codeName":"NamespaceNotFound","errmsg":"Unable to retrieve storageStats in $collStats stage :: caused by :: Collection [config.image_collection] not found."},"stats":{},"cmd":{"aggregate":"image_collection","cursor":{},"pipeline":[{"$collStats":{"storageStats":{"waitForLock":false,"numericOnly":true}}}],"$db":"config"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-14T11:35:16.018+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONNPOOL", "id":22576,   "ctx":"ReplNetwork","msg":"Connecting","attr":{"hostAndPort":"Ubuntu-2204-jammy-amd64-base:27017"}}

rs.config() on Primary
{
  set: 'rs0',
  date: ISODate('2024-11-14T11:36:01.498Z'),
  myState: 1,
  term: Long('3'),
  syncSourceHost: '',
  syncSourceId: -1,
  heartbeatIntervalMillis: Long('2000'),
  majorityVoteCount: 1,
  writeMajorityCount: 1,
  votingMembersCount: 1,
  writableVotingMembersCount: 1,
  optimes: {
    lastCommittedOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1731584161, i: 5 }), t: Long('3') },
    lastCommittedWallTime: ISODate('2024-11-14T11:36:01.474Z'),
    readConcernMajorityOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1731584161, i: 5 }), t: Long('3') },
    appliedOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1731584161, i: 5 }), t: Long('3') },
    durableOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1731584161, i: 5 }), t: Long('3') },
    writtenOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1731584161, i: 5 }), t: Long('3') },
    lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate('2024-11-14T11:36:01.474Z'),
    lastDurableWallTime: ISODate('2024-11-14T11:36:01.474Z'),
    lastWrittenWallTime: ISODate('2024-11-14T11:36:01.474Z')
  },
  lastStableRecoveryTimestamp: Timestamp({ t: 1731584157, i: 2 }),
  electionCandidateMetrics: {
    lastElectionReason: 'electionTimeout',
    lastElectionDate: ISODate('2024-11-14T09:11:55.719Z'),
    electionTerm: Long('3'),
    lastCommittedOpTimeAtElection: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 0, i: 0 }), t: Long('-1') },
    lastSeenWrittenOpTimeAtElection: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1731575489, i: 10 }), t: Long('2') },
    lastSeenOpTimeAtElection: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1731575489, i: 10 }), t: Long('2') },
    numVotesNeeded: 1,
    priorityAtElection: 1,
    electionTimeoutMillis: Long('10000'),
    numCatchUpOps: Long('0'),
    newTermStartDate: ISODate('2024-11-14T09:11:55.790Z'),
    wMajorityWriteAvailabilityDate: ISODate('2024-11-14T09:11:55.803Z')
  },
  members: [
    {
      _id: 0,
      name: 'Ubuntu-2204-jammy-amd64-base:27017',
      health: 1,
      state: 1,
      stateStr: 'PRIMARY',
      uptime: 8656,
      optime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1731584161, i: 5 }), t: Long('3') },
      optimeDate: ISODate('2024-11-14T11:36:01.000Z'),
      optimeWritten: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1731584161, i: 5 }), t: Long('3') },
      optimeWrittenDate: ISODate('2024-11-14T11:36:01.000Z'),
      lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate('2024-11-14T11:36:01.474Z'),
      lastDurableWallTime: ISODate('2024-11-14T11:36:01.474Z'),
      lastWrittenWallTime: ISODate('2024-11-14T11:36:01.474Z'),
      syncSourceHost: '',
      syncSourceId: -1,
      infoMessage: '',
      electionTime: Timestamp({ t: 1731575515, i: 1 }),
      electionDate: ISODate('2024-11-14T09:11:55.000Z'),
      configVersion: 10,
      configTerm: 3,
      self: true,
      lastHeartbeatMessage: ''
    },
    {
      _id: 1,
      name: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:27017',
      health: 1,
      state: 0,
      stateStr: 'STARTUP',
      uptime: 1925,
      optime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 0, i: 0 }), t: Long('-1') },
      optimeDurable: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 0, i: 0 }), t: Long('-1') },
      optimeWritten: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 0, i: 0 }), t: Long('-1') },
      optimeDate: ISODate('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'),
      optimeDurableDate: ISODate('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'),
      optimeWrittenDate: ISODate('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'),
      lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'),
      lastDurableWallTime: ISODate('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'),
      lastWrittenWallTime: ISODate('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'),
      lastHeartbeat: ISODate('2024-11-14T11:36:00.038Z'),
      lastHeartbeatRecv: ISODate('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'),
      pingMs: Long('9'),
      lastHeartbeatMessage: '',
      syncSourceHost: '',
      syncSourceId: -1,
      infoMessage: '',
      configVersion: -2,
      configTerm: -1
    }
  ],
  ok: 1,
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp({ t: 1731584161, i: 5 }),
    signature: {
      hash: Binary.createFromBase64('XXXXXXXXXX', 0),
      keyId: Long('XXXXXXXXXXXX')
    }
  },
  operationTime: Timestamp({ t: 1731584161, i: 5 })
}

rs.config() on Secondary
MongoServerError[NotYetInitialized]: no replset config has been received  


This output looks rather like rs.status() instead of rs.conf(). Please show us the configuration (rs.conf() and config file). I assume host XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:27017 is not reachable from the primary, maybe due to firewall settings.

Alright, so when you create the replica list, make sure that each host can talk to each other. This means that the hostnames (DNS) or IP Addresses must be specified properly.
My default replica configuration included the primary server's hostname as "my-ubuntu-server". So when the secondary node tried communicating back, it didn't.
I wish the logging was better.
